# How to show that $\hat{A}-\langle a\rangle$ is Hermitian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators

According to McQuarrie, we can write the definition of a Hermitian operator as an operator that satisfies $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f^*\hat{A}fdx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\hat{A^*}f^*dx$$ and the average value of the observable corresponding to $\hat{A}$ is given by $$\langle a\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Psi^*\hat{A}\Psi dx$$ How can I show that if $\hat{A}$ is Hermitian, then $(\hat{A}-\langle a\rangle)$ is Hermitian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall from the definition of the inner product that $\left<f,\lambda g\right>= \lambda\left<f,g\right> = \left<\lambda^* f,g\right>$ for any complex number $\lambda$.  It follows immediately that if $\lambda$ is real, then $\lambda \cdot  \mathbf 1$ is a Hermitian operator (where $\mathbf 1$ is the identity operator).

It is also easy to show that if two operators $A$ and $B$ are both Hermitian, then so is their sum/difference.  As a result, if $A$ is Hermitian, then $A-\left<a\right>\cdot \mathbf 1$ is Hermitian if and only if $\left<a\right>$ is real.

Your task is then to show that if $A$ is Hermitian, then $\left<a\right>$ is real.

Comment: $\int f^* (\hat{A}-\langle a \rangle)f dx=\int f^* \hat{A}f dx-\int f^*\langle a \rangle f dx$.

If $\hat{A}$ is Hermitian, then

$\int f^* \hat{A}f dx=\int f\hat{A}^* f^* dx.$

If $\langle a \rangle$ is real ($\langle a \rangle=\langle a \rangle ^*$), then
 
$\int f^*\langle a \rangle f dx=\int f \langle a \rangle^* f^* dx$.

Thus,

$\int f^* \hat{A}f dx-\int f^*\langle a \rangle f dx=\int f \hat{A}^* f^* dx-\int f \langle a \rangle^* f^* dx=\int f (\hat{A}-\langle a \rangle)^* f^* dx$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Cerlosh Yes, that's correct.